# How do I get value of a key value pair in react?

Tags: reactjs

I have the following scenario:
A form where one of the input fields value is dependent on the dropdown list selection. Example if i select 'shirts' i want to populate the input field with URL to image of a shirt. I have the following code. I need help with selecting the right value corresponding to the user selection:

```
class ProductAdd extends React.Component{

constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = { defaultPrice: '$',
                    categoryValue: '',
                    URL: [
                        {
                            shirts: "https://www.istockphoto.com/photo/formal-shirt-with-button-down-collar-isolated-on-white-gm856917576-141225609",
                            jeans: "https://www.istockphoto.com/photo/blue-jeans-isolated-with-clipping-path-gm600373506-103229995",
                            jackets: "https://www.istockphoto.com/photo/black-hoodie-mock-up-gm695933044-128721993",
                            sweaters: "https://www.istockphoto.com/photo/formal-shirt-with-button-down-collar-isolated-on-white-gm856917576-141225609",
                            accessories: "https://www.shutterstock.com/image-vector/hair-accessories-woman-items-stylist-salon-1451306021"
                        }
                    ],
                };
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);     
}

handleSubmit(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    const form = document.forms.productAdd;
    const product = {
        productName: form.productName.value, 
        category: form.category.value,
        price: form.price.value,
        image: form.image.value
        }
        this.props.createProduct(product);
        form.productName.value="";
        form.category.value="";
        form.price.value="";
        form.image.value="";
    }

handleChange(e){
    this.setState( { defaultPrice: e.target.value });
}



render(){
    let btnClass = [
        'btn',
        'clearfix'
      ]
      btnClass = btnClass.join(' ');

      Object.keys(this.state.URL).map(i => alert(this.state.URL['shirts']));

      //console.log(this.state.URL.shirts);

    return(
        <div>
            <form name="productAdd" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className="form">
                <div className="div1">
                    Category <br/>
                    <select name="category" className="selectBox"  onChange={ (e) => this.setState( { categoryValue: e.target.value }) }>
                        <option value="shirts">Shirts</option>
                        <option value="jeans">Jeans</option>
                        <option value="jackets">Jackets</option>
                        <option value="sweaters">Sweaters</option>
                        <option value="accessories">Accessories</option>
                    </select><br/><br/>
                    Product Name <br/>
                    <input type="text" name="productName" /><br/><br/>
                </div>
                <div className="div2">
                    Price Per Unit <br/>
                    <input ref="price" type="text" name="price" onChange={ this.handleChange } value={this.state.defaultPrice} /><br/><br/>                    
                    Image URL<br/>
                    <input type="text" name="image" value={this.state.URL[this.state.categoryValue]} /><br/><br/>
                </div>

                <button className={btnClass}>Add Product</button>
            </form>
    </div>
    );
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `URL` prop is an array:

```js
URL: [
  {
    shirts: "https://www.istockphoto.com/photo/formal-shirt-with-button-down-collar-isolated-on-white-gm856917576-141225609",
    jeans: "https://www.istockphoto.com/photo/blue-jeans-isolated-with-clipping-path-gm600373506-103229995",
    jackets: "https://www.istockphoto.com/photo/black-hoodie-mock-up-gm695933044-128721993",
    sweaters: "https://www.istockphoto.com/photo/formal-shirt-with-button-down-collar-isolated-on-white-gm856917576-141225609",
    accessories: "https://www.shutterstock.com/image-vector/hair-accessories-woman-items-stylist-salon-1451306021"
  }
]
```

So either you need to convert it to an object (which you can use as a map) or you need to get the first item in your array and then select the correct entry.

**Option 1**

```js
URL: {
  shirts: "https://www.istockphoto.com/photo/formal-shirt-with-button-down-collar-isolated-on-white-gm856917576-141225609",
  jeans: "https://www.istockphoto.com/photo/blue-jeans-isolated-with-clipping-path-gm600373506-103229995",
  jackets: "https://www.istockphoto.com/photo/black-hoodie-mock-up-gm695933044-128721993",
  sweaters: "https://www.istockphoto.com/photo/formal-shirt-with-button-down-collar-isolated-on-white-gm856917576-141225609",
  accessories: "https://www.shutterstock.com/image-vector/hair-accessories-woman-items-stylist-salon-1451306021"
}
```

**Option 2**

```js
this.state.URL[0][this.state.categoryValue]
```

If you are new to Javascript, then you might have been confused by the square brackets. Javascript is rather unusual in that you can [access object properties with square brackets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) containing variables.

Comment: Thank you, that helped!